# Get Filepath, and move the files in an other Directory if they contain an ID in the name

Tags: c#

Basically, I need to check if a file exist in 4 version which mean that a 11 digits code appear in the filename.
Once the check is done I need to move the file on another Server.

My problem is that I get the ID, and I do know when an ID appear 4 times, but I don't know how to get the files Path from the ID I got and then move the files.

Any kind of help would be super appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string ExtractIDFromFileName(string filename)
    {
        return filename.Split('_').Last();
    }

    Dictionary<string, int> GetDictOfIDCounts()
    {
        List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Desktop/Script/tiptop", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
        allfiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Desktop/Script/tiptop", "*.top").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList());
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var x in allfiles)

        {

            string fileID = ExtractIDFromFileName(x);
            if (dict.ContainsKey(fileID))
            {
                dict[fileID]++;

            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(fileID, 1);

            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    var result = GetDictOfIDCounts();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("{0} > {1}", item.Key, item.Value);

        if (item.Value == 4)

        {
            //When we know that those ID appear 4 times, I need to grab back the FilePath and then move the files in an other DIR.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} > {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use File.Move: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.7.2

It's pretty straightforward. Make the ID in your dictionary the full path of the source file, then File.Move(dict.Key, some-variable-holding-the-new-directory-and-file-name);

Since you're going to want to use the filepath, just switch over to using the instance version of Directory & File: DirectoryInfo & FileInfo:

replace

```
List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Desktop/Script/tiptop", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```

with

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users/Desktop/Script/tiptop");
            var allFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

Make the FileInfo the key of the dictionary. Then you can do things like

```
dict.Key.FullName
```

Comment: That's the current problem, getting the full path of the sources won't count the correct number of files, For exemple : "C:/file1prefix8888" and "C:/file6otherprefix8888"

Comment: I need a way to get the filepath, only if it contains the ID

Comment: @Squ3D try using the FileInfo object instead of passing around strings, see my edit

Comment: Thanks but if I do this, I will loose the verification on the .top file

Comment: @Squ3D okay, it's hard to say since your code doesn't compile at all and has some syntactical errors (perhaps when you copied here) but it seems like you have some design issues then. You'll probably want to fix your code, phrase your question better, and provide some sample filenames you're working with to get better answers.

Comment: @Squ3D maybe I'm confused then, isn't string ExtractIDFromFileName(string filename) supposed to be a function? It's within in the Main method though. Same thing with GetDictOfIDCounts()

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get files you want, it uses `GroupBy` on the ID and `Count()`. I haven't compiled it so there might be errors.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Script\tiptop", "*.*")
             .Where(file => { 
                 var ext = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower();
                 return ext == ".txt" || ext == ".top";
               })
             .Select(file => new { Path = file, Id = file.Split('_').Last()})
             .GroupBy(file => file.Id)
             .Where(grp => grp.Count() >= 4)
             .SelectMany(x => x)
             .Select(x => x.Path);
```

Another solution would be to use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, int>`. When adding a new key to the `Dictionary` you would add `new List<string> { x }` so that you would keep the file names in the list of ids. Instead of checking for the `item.Value == 4` in you `if` you could check the size of the list like `item.Count == 4`. Then you still have the file names so you may use them to move the files.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not able to fix it

Comment: I removed a parenthesis. It does compile. Does it work for you?